# "Does a true Java decompiler exist?" Needs to be considered for being reopened

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

My question from last night was closed, but it does conform to the standard format. Obviously this type of question could *lead* to a discussion type answer, but for someone who is familiar with decompilation, this can be answered.

Per the FAQ, good questions can cover the following:

- software tools commonly used by programmers
- practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

The question fits two of the four possible 'good questions'.

[does-a-true-java-decompiler-exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880138/does-a-true-java-decompiler-exist/)

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: People pointed out problems with that too-vague (NARQ) and subjective ("Not Constructive") question.  You made no attempt to improve the question (which you still can do, BTW). The only problem is that it took 7 hours to close.  I'd like to get that time down to 1 hour, or less, on questions like that. ;)

Comment: In case you're wondering, [voting is different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). So far, 8 users think the question should remain closed. The only problem *I* see is your usage of the word [decompiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler). It doesn't mean what you think it does.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is not a good fit for *Stack Overflow* for several reasons:

- It is asking for a shopping recommendation, [which is off-topic](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)
- It lacks to show your effort. What did you try and where are you stuck. *Stack Overflow* is not a research assistant.
- Your question can be answered in one word: yes or no. That is not really constructive.

Comment: 1) Like in the FAQ, programming tools are encouraged. I don't know what you mean by shopping recommendations. I want to learn WHY it isn't feasible.
2) Little effort? I keep my questions succinct; I've researched, downloaded, and used JAD, JD, and Fernflower, along with reading documentation. Someone on this forum knows more than me
3) What one word explains the intricacies of decompilation?

Comment: @RubberDuck That is a common mistake. It is not what that line in the FAQ means.

Comment: You can ask when you have a specific question **about** a programming tool. But not **what** to use. Such questions get outdated and have no use for future visitors. And the answers are opinion based because everyone has a prefered tool.

Comment: @juergend So pray tell, what one word explains the difficulties of decompilation? The first part of my question really points out that nothing exists, and the second asks _why_.

Comment: I was refering to your question title. BTW it does not match your question body then.

Answer (score 6):

There is a second flaw in the Question which makes it unanswerable.  You used the phrase *"all fail to perfectly generate source"* as a key criterion, and then proceeded to base the rest of your question on this.

The problem is that that phrase is fatally ambiguous.  What is "perfect" source code?

- Is it code that is identical to the original source code?
- Is it code that is identical to the original source code *sans* comments?
- Is it code that is functionally equivalent to the original source code?

I and others pointed this out in our attempted Answers, and in comments on the Question ... which have since been deleted (sigh).  You have *still* failed to address this problem, even though the Answers don't appear to have answered your question (based on *your* comments on my Answer.)

---

And just to address one point that you raised above:

> "What one word explains the intricacies of decompilation?"

It is totally unrealistic to expect an SO Answer to explain the intricacies of decompilation to you.  It is an extremely specialized topic, and would (most likely) take a small book to describe adequately.  So maybe the 2nd part of your original question requires a two word answer - "Too complicated".

And as I pointed out in another now-deleted comment (sigh):

- If you intend to implement your own decompiler you need to do the research yourself.
- If you don't intend to do that ... knowing how a decompiler works is not going to make a real difference to you.  (Apart from satisfying your curiosity, that is ...)